# countryId is required. Enter and try again

Tags: magento2

My website is multi-store

Magento after upgrade 2.2.7 to 2.3.4, facing an issue which creates new order as below

```
countryId is required. Enter and try again.
```

On debug I came across that issue is in file

> [2020-02-14 10:14:59] report.CRITICAL: "countryId" is required. Enter
>   and try again. {"exception":"[object]
>   (Magento\Framework\Exception\InputException(code: 0): \"countryId\"
>   is required. Enter and try again. at
>   vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/ResourceModel/AddressRepository.php:133)"}

I have verified this link
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/14232 but not working

Following code is causing the issue

```
/*$countryElement = $this->_form->getElement('country_id');

    $this->processCountryOptions($countryElement);

    if ($countryElement->getValue()) {
        $countryId = $countryElement->getValue();
        $countryElement->setValue(null);
        foreach ($countryElement->getValues() as $country) {
            if ($country['value'] == $countryId) {
                $countryElement->setValue($countryId);
            }
        }
    }
    if ($countryElement->getValue() === null) {
        $countryElement->setValue(
            $this->directoryHelper->getDefaultCountry($this->getStore())
        );
    }*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Stores -> General -> State Option and then unselect all country** and clear cache and try again

Comment: Not working. We have already this solution

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code it looks like this when you are [creating an order in the admin area](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3/app/code/Magento/Sales/Block/Adminhtml/Order/Create/Form/Address.php)?

It's hard to give a detailed answer without seeing your code base but these questions might help:

1. Are there any custom changes to the address form that might mean the country id is removed or missing? (This might have been "ok" to do in 2.2 but not 2.3)
2. Have you tried logging/dumping the value of `$this->_form->getElement('country_id');` at that point?
3. Does this happen when you create an order through the front end as well?

Comment: 1. We have not made any changes, 2. It is returning 'Null', 3. In frontend it is working fine

Answer (score 0):

You need to run this command:

```
update eav_attribute set is_required = 0 where attribute_code = 'country_id'
```

Comment: We tried this but not working

Comment: please clear cache and try to run the command again.

Comment: After making changes I have ran all magento commands

Comment: No it is not working